# SQL - Query control record chosen by group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I want to perform a query with "group by" on table but want to apply 3 rules on the records that will by chosen for each group. Is this possible? Using Mysql SGBD.

```
idMatch  Country  VideoType VideoId
1        Pt       High      vidZbr  
1        Pt       High      vidXpto
1        Pt       low       vioptr
1        Pt       normal    vidfff
2        Pt       low       vidfgg
2        Pt       normal    vid
3        Pt       low       videop
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM videos_extended where country = 'Pt' group by idMatch;
```

**Wanted Result for grouping rules:** (add videotype 'High' if exists else add videotype 'normal' if exists or 'low' if all else fails for this 'idMatch' group)

```
idMatch  Country  VideoType VideoId
1        Pt       High      vidZbr
2        Pt       normal    vid
3        Pt       low       videop
```

Comment: add an `ORDER BY IdMatch, VideoType`. If `VideoType` is not an enum, you will have to wrap it with a `CASE`  I suppose.

Comment: How are VideoId's ordered? In your result for "High", you picked vidZbr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select two rows for the row: "1", "Pt", "High". It can be improved if you specify how to pick a VideoId:

```
select *
from videos_extended video inner join
(
    select idMatch, Country, 
       min(case VideoType 
           when 'high' then 1 
           when 'normal' then 2
           when 'low' then 3
           else 4 
         end
       ) rank
    from videos_extended
    group by idMatch, Country
) maxType
on maxType.idMatch = video.idMatch 
   and maxType.Country = video.Country
   and maxType.rank = (
      case video.VideoType 
         when 'high' then 1 
         when 'normal' then 2
         when 'low' then 3
         else 4 
      end
   )
```

Comment: This technic works like a charm! In this case I don't need a specific videoid so it does not matter wich one is chosen. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if VideoType were integer, otherwise you can use CASE or this query:

```
SELECT idMatch, Country, VideoType, MAX(VideoId) AS MVidId FROM videos_extended INNER JOIN (SELECT idMatch AS idm, MIN(SUBSTRING(VideoType, 3, 1)) AS vv FROM videos_extended GROUP BY idMatch, Country) AS T ON idMatch = idm AND SUBSTRING(VideoType, 3, 1) = vv GROUP BY idMatch, Country, VideoType
```

Comment: I have marked lunr's answer as a solution but this should work as well